# Convert a pandas data frame filled with values in curly brackets to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas dataframe with values in curly brackets, and I want to convert it to a Pandas dataframe with the same values but instead of curly brackets, they have to be converted to NumPy arrays. This is an example of an instance of my dataframe:
[An instance of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUATh.png)

```
0, 5, '{{{1., 0.}, {0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.}}}',
   '{{{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}}, {{0.3333333333333333, 0.}, {0., 1.}}}',
   '{{{0., 0.}, {0., 0.}}, {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.}}}',
   '{0., 0.041666666666666664, 0., 0., 0.}', '{0., 0., 2., 1.}'
```

I want this instance of the dataframe to be like this:

```
0, 5, array([[[1., 0.], [0., 0.]], [[0., 0.], [0., 0.]]]),
   array([[[0., 0.], [1., 0.]], [[0.3333333333333333, 0.], [0., 1.]]]),
   array([[[0., 0.], [0., 0.]], [[0., 0.], [0., 0.]]]),
   array([0., 0.041666666666666664, 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 2., 1.])
```

Comment: Hello, please edit your question and include the `dataframe` as text so we can use it instead of typing it all over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I took the liberty of assuming those curly brackets in your original DataFrame are strings.

You can use a combination of a lambda expression and `ast.literal_eval(x)`.

```
import ast
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.array(ast.literal_eval(str(x).replace('{', '[').replace('}', ']')), 
                                    dtype=object))
```

This expression applies a function which first converts a value to string. It then replaces `'{'` with `'['` and `'}'` with `']'` and after that it uses `ast.literal_eval` to convert a string to a `list`. `np.array` is there if you really want it to be a `numpy` array but it isn't necessary.

From another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894296/15954959):

> With `ast.literal_eval` you can safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply:

1. replace all `{` with `[` and replace all `}` with `]` and use python `eval` function to convert it into a python `list`
2. create a `np.array()` from python list

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series(['0', '5', '{{1.,0.},{0.,0.},{0.,0.}}', '2', '{{4.5, 5}, {0.3, 0.6}}', '200'])
data = data.apply(lambda x: np.array(eval(str(x).replace('{', '[').replace('}', ']'))) if '{' in str(x) else float(x))
print(data)
```